# Operator Sorting Error

Tags: python, sorting, typeerror

I'm trying to sort a dictionary of lists by the first, then second list entries. From the Sorting how-to, I'm trying to apply the operator, but am doing it wrong. Any and all help is much appreciated!

```
my_dict = { 111: [50, 2, 34], 122: [50 , 4, 45], 133: [40, 1, 12], 144: [20, 5, 7] }

s = sorted(my_dict, key = itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
sorted(s, key=itemgetter(1))
```

giving the error below. I'm still fairly new at this and don't understand the error fully.

```
    s = sorted(my_dict, key = itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `dict`s are *unordered*. It doesn't make sense to say "sort a dict". What is actually happening is you are sorting the result of *iterating over a dict*, which is the dict's keys. So `itemgetter` is acting on the keys, which are `int`s, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you, Juanpa. Is there a way to sort a dictionary? This is the method that I keep seeing.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to say "sort a dictionary". Dictionaries are *inherently unordered*.

Comment: Thank you, again. Any recommendations on how to store and retrieve auction-style bids? I need to correlate the bid price and number of items to specific, unique bids.

Comment: What isn't working with a regular `dict`?

Comment: I thought that a key can only have one value tied to it. I am pretty new to all of this :)

Comment: You should probably ask a question detailing this. It's hard to say anything without really knowing more.